# Rails CSRF validation not working with proxy server in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, proxy, csrf, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a simple feedback form on my Rails 5 app, which is failing CSRF validation on `POST`s - but only in production. More specifically, the production server is `foo.example.com`, but the service is accessed by a proxy server `proxy.example.com`. There's an Nginx server running on the proxy that routes requests to the appropriate application server.

If I browse directly to `http://foo.example.com`, and submit the form, everything is fine. But submitting the same form when viewed as `https://proxy.example.com`, I get the CSRF failure. There are two key differences between the two access routes: the request rewriting by the proxy, and `http` vs. `https`. I'm not sure which is the relevant factor.

One theory was that the domain used by the session store was not coming out correctly, but I tried various variants of passing `domain:` to `Rails.application.config.session_store`, but none of them made any differences. After that, I've rather run out of hypotheses as to where to look.

Comment: Have you looked at this [thread](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2734)?

Comment: @AbM Thanks but I already have, yes. It doesn't match my situation: I am not creating an API (or using Devise, as it happens, but that's incidental).

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? We're not running a proxy server but some of our clients are behind high security networks (and maybe a virtual instance) and running into this error. Thanks!

Comment: @JoshPinter No, we never did find a solution. In the end, given that the form wasn't submitting critical information and didn't require a user to be logged in, we turned off CSRF.

Comment: @IanDickinson Thanks for the reply. I turned off CRSF as well, but then ran into numerous other issues with the session being nil. My guess for our situation is that our customer was using CITRIX to connect to the web app and they had cookies turned off so the session token couldn't be stored there. Anyway, confusing stuff.

Comment: How is your `session_store` configured? Have you set `secure: true`?